# How to dynamically set textview from json response android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I need to get dynamic string and need to store in textview(id is trainer_title_text in xml). How to do this? Response output from json is:
1.Private trainers 2. Government Trainers. How to assign list of strings in textview without changing alignment in xml?

Here is code:

```
public class DynamicTextView extends Fragment {
private TextView TitleTypes;
private String StrDescription;
private RelativeLayout relative;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trainers_certification,
            container, false);
            JSONArray    jsonTypePrice=jsonData.getJSONArray("trainer_type_items");
              for (int i = 0; i < jsonTypePrice.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject object = jsonTypePrice.getJSONObject(i);
                  strType=object.getString("type"); 
           //here i am getting type     as 1.private Test 2.public Test 
                  strCost=object.getString("cost");
                  Log.e("service call types", strType);               
              }
        LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
      relative.addView(textView);

      textView.setText(strType);
  I used like this but it's always setting only one data.
  Output is:
  private Test  

 Here is xml: where id is trainer_title_text i need to assign list of strings in vertical.


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/product_bg" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/product_main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trainer_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Title:Chairperson,Department of Physical Education" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/product_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/product_main_image_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/trainer_description"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/product_main_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:onClick="onclick"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/default_thumb" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <com.contus.sportscorner.views.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/product_images"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/product_list_image_size"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_image"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/desc_holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_images"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trainer_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/title_bg"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Types of Trainer"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view_divider_desc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/trainer_title"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/trainer_title_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view_divider_desc"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Private"
                    android:textColor="@color/sub_textcolor" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/event_info_holder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/trainer_title_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_info_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/title_bg"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Cost for his Services"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/event_info_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_info_title"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/blue" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/event_calendar_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_info_divider"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/event_time_holder"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_calendar_divider"
                        android:background="#E9FDE8"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_time"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Private"
                            android:textColor="@color/sub_textcolor" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/price"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:text="QAR650.00" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/event_street_divider"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_time_holder"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/event_info_holders"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/event_info_holder"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/event_info_titles"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/title_bg"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:text="Discounts"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="visible" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/event_info_dividers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_info_titles"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/blue" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/event_calendar_dividers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_info_dividers"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/event_time_holders"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_calendar_dividers"
                        android:background="#E9FDE8"
                        android:padding="5dp" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/event_times"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Students"
                            android:textColor="@color/sub_textcolor" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/prices"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:text="20%" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/event_street_dividers"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/event_time_holders"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/event_contact_dividers"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/product_main"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/title_bg" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/event_contact_dividers"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signInButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_radius"
                android:text="Book an Appointment"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/food_and_health"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_radius"
                android:text="Food and health tips and tricks"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder to gather all info you need to display this way:

```
JSONArray jsonTypePrice=jsonData.getJSONArray("trainer_type_items");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonTypePrice.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject object = jsonTypePrice.getJSONObject(i);
     strType=object.getString("type"); 

     // Note the new-line we're adding at the end
     builder.append(strType).append("\n");

     strCost=object.getString("cost");
     Log.e("service call types", strType);               
}
```

And then just add the multi-line text we built to your textView.

```
textView.setText(builder.toString());
```

Comment: but it displays only one result.